# Significance of curly braces in string comparison (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I have to modify a batch script which I notice has this style of parsing command-line flags, for example:

```
if /I {%1} == {-d} (
```

Is there any reason why curly braces are used? As far as I know, they don't really have any significance in batch scripts.
Interestingly, the commit history shows that curly braces were introduced after code review, and the pre-review version used square brackets:

```
if /I [%1] == [-d] (
```

Initial coders/reviewers are gone, so I'm asking here why these braces/brackets would be necessary, and whether it's any different than using doublequotes instead, or even no quotes at all.

Comment: It's one of many methods used to protect against `%1` being unspecified, which leads to its being replaced by *nothing* and hence a syntax error as `if == whatever (` is illegal. Braces were used, brackets, simply pre/succeeding with a character... Normally, "quoting both sides" of the comparison operator is used. Or `set "somevar=%~1"` followed by `if defined somevar ...` on the next line

Comment: @Magoo Thanks for your comment, makes sense. Would you care to post it as the answer? I'd accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one of many methods used to protect against `%1` being unspecified, which leads to its being replaced by nothing and hence a syntax error as `if == whatever (` is illegal. Braces were used, brackets, simply pre/succeeding with a character... Normally, "quoting both sides" of the comparison operator is used, which also protects against syntax errors in case there are any spaces in the string or variable content.

Or

```
set "somevar=%~1"
if defined somevar ...
```